KeyboardInterrupt is not catched when blocking work is done
To stop the following code one will need to press Ctrl-C twice, however the second raised KeyboardInterrupt exception is not catched by the inner try-catch inside the start_consuming method.
import asyncio


async def start_consuming():
    try:
        await asyncio.Future()
    except:
        try:
            await asyncio.Future()
        except:
            pass


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(start_consuming())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

Why?

I cannot reproduce this. I've added debug prints right after both excepts and they each get printed after respective first and second interrupt.

Are you using python 3.12?

Yes, 3.12.0 on Windows.

I am on MacOS Ventura using python 3.12.2

I think I see what you mean. Interrupts are excepted as they should; but there is still an KeyboardInterrupt exception propagated and printed.

Why is that not handled?

It is not like it seems. Here is your program with some debug prints added.
import asyncio

async def start_consuming():
    try:
        await asyncio.Future()
    except BaseException as b:
        print(1, repr(b))

    try:
        await asyncio.Future()
    except BaseException as b:
        print(2, repr(b))

async def main():
    try:
        await asyncio.gather(start_consuming())
    except BaseException as b:
        print(3, repr(b))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except BaseException as b:
        print (4, repr(b))


The output slightly edited:
^C 1 CancelledError()

^C 2 CancelledError()

3 CancelledError()

4 KeyboardInterrupt()

I don't have a fully detailed explanation, but it is clear that when the ctrl-C interrupts arrive, the start_consuming coroutine is not executing, because it is not ready.
The interrupt (exception) is then caught ("catched") by the asyncio itself. Everything else is in my opinion an asyncio shutdown & cleanup in action. The ctrl-C interrupt is then raised by asyncio.run() during the exit from asyncio.
I'd like to add a note regarding the asyncio shutdown, "swallowing" the cancellation exception - which is also BaseException - is against the rules. Docs: "This exception can be caught to perform custom operations when asyncio Tasks are cancelled. In almost all situations the exception must be re-raised."

Could you clarify "when the ctrl-C interrupts arrive, the start_consuming coroutine is not executing, because it is not ready"?

I wrote that, because an incorrect impression that the task is hanging between the try and except and therefore should get the exception and handle it there could have emerged. In reality, every await FUTURE when the FUTURE is not done will cause a task switch. The current task must wait until the FUTURE gets its value. Another task could run in the meantime if it is ready. In this case there is no other task. The asyncio waits in the event loop for something to happen (in detail: I/O or scheduled callbacks). And what happens is the ctrl-c interrupt.

So you are saying that the code is not stuck in the second try-except when the first CancelledError is raised?

@asant-leitha. Yes. An async code should never "stuck", i.e. should never do blocking I/O or an extremely long CPU computation. Make a test, start also a second task (e.g. print "hello" every second in a loop) and that second task will continue to run.
